# How to verify the logged in user using Javascript in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I need to check whether the logged in user is a administrator or non-admin user by using JavaScript in sharepoint designer or content editor webpart.

Can anybody suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery and SPServices to examine the group a logged in user belongs to, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841985/sharepoint-10-lists-want-to-limit-form-fields-per-user-groups/8847834#8847834) which explains the principle. In that case, it hides an element if a user belongs to a particular group.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `HasRights` javascript function defined in SharePoints `core.js`, you just have to pass the lower (limit) permission mask as well as the upper limit.

See the post about [Checking Permissions with Javascript in Sharepoint 2007](http://henry-chong.com/2010/10/checking-permissions-with-javascript-in-sharepoint-2007/) and the [list of permission masks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304243%28PROT.13%29.aspx). As you want to check whether it is an administrator you could try the `ManageWeb` permission mask: `0x0000000040000000`

---

**Edit:** Another possibility is not using the `HasRights` function, but a `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` to simply set a global Javascript variable. An example you can find here: [SharePoint: Run JavaScript based on user rights / permissions](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/07/sharepoint-run-javascript-based-on-user.html). This of course means extra markup (and doesn't work in a content editor webpart), but it does work.

Comment: Thanks for the links.. I want to verify the user in newform.aspx of a servey list. Can we use the HasRights method in that page?.. If yes then what are the parameters I have to pass ti it

Comment: I don't have a SharePOint 2007 availalbe, so I can't test. As long as the `core.js` is loaded you can use HasRights. The parameters are explained in the links I posted.

Comment: I just added the below script in my content editor webpart. No result. Can you check the code and let me know what needs to be done. I checked the HasRights is defined or not in core.jas, it is not defined in it. <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> if(HasRights(0x0, 0x0000000040000000)) { alert("You have admin rights."); } </script>

Comment: This seems to always return `true` for me.. even when I don't have permission. I do see it in core.js though.

Answer (score -1):

On the web part, after you edit it there is a a field called target audience. You can only put groups here so put the user in group first.