# Setting up a Data View Conditional Format for MOSS 2007 that targets a specific group

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, dataview, conditional-formatting

I need to figure out a solution to allow only a specific group of users with permission to view a List Item in Editform.aspx.  I created a custom form which would allow me to apply conditional formatting for a specific table row.  I had used the advance formatting XPATH expression **"ddwrt:IfHasRights(16)"** which worked with any group that had contribute rights or below, but I also need to exclude other groups like tier 1 - 3, Site Builder, Designer, etc or above "Approval" status.  The purpose is to only allow a very selected group of individuals (I created a group called "Approvers") to see the hidden table row.

The current working on MOSS 2007 standard version.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Jason

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery and SPServices to examine the group a logged in user belongs to, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841985/sharepoint-10-lists-want-to-limit-form-fields-per-user-groups/8847834#8847834) which explains the principle. In that case, it hides an element if a user belongs to a particular group.