# Populating Drop down on the basis of User Group

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

I am developing the SharePoint Portal in 2010 where i will be using a Dropdown with values in it. These Values will depend on the group to which the user belongs.

**For Eg.**

If **Drop Values are A, B , C, D, E**

and there is a **Group XYZ**

**If User A  logs in & he belongs to Group XYZ the Drop down should show: A B E**

**Else the drop down should show : C, D**

Anybody having an idea on how to do it. Please Share it.

Thanks
Kishan Srivastava

Comment: Do you need to know how to handle user groups, the drop down, or both?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...!! I want to create this functionality within the library of SharePoint using a column(having drop down values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'no code' way would be to have the column as a lookup column into another list which.was security trimmed at the item level. Or you could have folders in this list and use these as the security containers for the items. Code ways involve the use of client side scripting. I'd recommend the spservices codeplex library to act as the javascript wrapper to the Sharepoint webservices. I'll think this through a bit more if the first way doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Ciaran...!!

I Tried using the spservices codeplex library but still i need to select the extra option which the user belong. This is an extra task that i want to skip. What I want is when a user logs the Group to which the user belongs should be automatically identified & the drop down values should be populated with value that correspond to that particular group. 


For Eg.

If Drop Values are A, B , C, D, E

and there is a Group XYZ

If User A logs in & he belongs to Group XYZ the Drop down should show: A B E

Else the drop down should show : C, D

Comment: Hi, I see you asked the same question on Sharepoint.stackexchange. the answer there expands on mine and is very good. Go with that one.

Comment: Thank You..!! I have Done with it..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SPServices code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841985/sharepoint-10-lists-want-to-limit-form-fields-per-user-groups/8847834#8847834) to understand if a user belongs to a group.

Comment: Thanks Paul I have done this using the Lookup by creating the 2 different group and giving them a Item based permissions. But anyways thanks for your help, the way u suggested is also good...!!!

Answer (score 0):

agreed with SPServices method it has very good for me